# Replacing brackets with parentheses for \textcite, Biblatex numeric-comp

Tags: biblatex, formatting, brackets

I'm trying to modify the numeric-comp style so in-text citations appear with parentheses rather than brackets for both `\cite` and `\textcite` i.e. `[1]` becomes `(1)` and `Smith et al. [1]` becomes `Smith et al. (1)`.

This was no problem for `\cite` - I just changed the command:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

For `\textcite`, I assumed that I could redefine the `textcite` macro replacing `\bibopenbracket` with `\bibopenparen` and `\bibclosebracket` with `\bibcloseparen`, like so:

```
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\cbx@tempa
    \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
 \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \addspace\bibopenparen
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibcloseparen\multicitedelim}}
```

But when I compile (after running biber) this I get the error "Argument of `\@secondoftwo` has an extra }". In fact this happens even if I renew the `textcite` macro to be exactly as it appears in `numeric-comp.cbx`. Is there something I'm not understanding here, or is it a bug? And is there another way?

(I'm using TeXShop 3.21 on Mac OS X.)

Minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, backend=biber, firstinits=true, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{testref.bib}
@article{a_reference,
    Author = {Smith, A A and Jones, Z Z},
    Journal = {A Journal},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {267--277},
    Title = {A title},
    Volume = {75},
    Year = {2008}}
\end{filecontents}



\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\cbx@tempa
     \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \addspace\bibopenparen
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibcloseparen\multicitedelim}}

\bibliography{testref}
\begin{document}

We \textbackslash cite \cite{a_reference} and then \textbackslash textcite -\textcite{a_reference}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please give `\makeatletter` before your definition.

Comment: @JagathAR an answer?

Comment: @cmhughes: Do I need to write this as answer?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: Actually this question does not have an answer in its alleged duplicate. People looking for an answer might find useful http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341041/28685