# Biblatex numeric style: replace square with round brackets in both citations and bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Suppose you have this MWE using `numeric` style with Biblatex

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} % needed if also biblatex is used

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Conclusion}
Adams said ``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \cite{adams1995hitchhiker}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What is the best way to replace square brackets with round brackets in both citations and bibliography?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

With `biblatex-ext` styles, things are a little bit easier since you can use their cite delimiter feature.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelimsAlias{cite}{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
Lorem \autocites{sigfridsson}{worman}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

### Without `biblate-ext`

With

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

you get round brackets in the bibliography, for citations you need to copy the definitions from `numeric.cbx` and change `\mkbibbrackets` into `\mkbibparens`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibparens]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}
```

---

More radical is

```
\renewrobustcmd{\mkbibbrackets}{\mkbibparens}
```

or even

```
\let\bibopenbracket\bibopenparen
\let\bibclosebracket\bibcloseparen
```

where all square brackets are replaced by round brackets. This can lead to problems if you do want square brackets in other places in your citations/bibliography.

---

Note that you will need more intricate tricks for some of the more advanced `numeric`-derived styles and `\textcite`.

Comment: @mmj Note that the trick is not only radical, but might also take things too far (`\mkbibrackets` will now always come out as `\mkbibparens`, not only the citation/bibliography label brackets).

Comment: I thought there must be an option to toggle this somewhere, as it seemed an obvious thing to want to do, but I couldn't find one and gather that's because there isn't one. Is the idea that somebody who wanted this should really create a new version of the `numeric` styles? It would be nice if there was something like `csquotes` which could flip inner and outer brackets in the same way as inner and outer quotes.

Comment: @cfr Unfortunately, there is no such thing. If it only was the `labelnumberwidth` field format, that would be OK, but the problem really is that one has to delve into the `.cbx` files, modify some `\DeclareCiteCommand`s and even some bibmacros for `\textcite`. Maybe we should try and make that easier in the core...

Comment: @moewe It does seem a bit surprising this can't be toggled when so much else can. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: The radical trick seems to work (at least with basic usage) even with `numeric-comp` style.