# How change brackets to parenthesis in citations?

Tags: biblatex

How change from:

> Einstein [2] fez um bom trabalho. As pessoas precisam de ajuda [2].

to:

> Einstein (2) fez um bom trabalho. As pessoas precisam de ajuda [2].

My code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}

@article{einstein,
author = {Albert Einstein},
  title = {the true about tree},
  journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
  year = {1905},
  volume = {322},
  number = {10},
  pages = {891-921}
}

@article{einstein2,
  author = {Albert Einstein},
  title = {the lie about tree},
  journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
  year = {1906},
  volume = {322},
  number = {10},
  pages = {891-921}
  }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}%

\begin{document}


\chapter{Capitulinho}
\section{Section}

\textcite{einstein} fez um bom trabalho.
As pessoas precisam de ajuda \cite{einstein}.

\textcite{einstein2} fez um bom trabalho.
As pessoas precisam de ajuda \cite{einstein2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And if I use *\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}*, how change from:

> Einstein (2) fez um bom trabalho. As pessoas precisam de ajuda (2).

to:

> Einstein (2) fez um bom trabalho. As pessoas precisam de ajuda [2].

Comment: Does this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341041/105447 help?

Comment: If you have a recent version of biblatex (3.11), there is also [biblatex-ext](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) which allows for user options on the citation delimiters (see section 5.3).

Comment: Did my answer help you? Or is there something wrong with it? On this site you can accept an answer if it solved your issue and upvote answers that helped you. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)'s `ext-numeric` style (`\usepackage[style=ext-numeric]{biblatex}`). You will only need

```
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
```

to get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{sigfridsson} fez um bom trabalho.
As pessoas precisam de ajuda \cite{sigfridsson}.

\textcite{nussbaum} fez um bom trabalho.
As pessoas precisam de ajuda \cite{nussbaum}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

*edit: `biblatex-ext` [v0.4 changes the names of a few macros](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/7d2e2f1be11f68dcdec62897e1e2afeaa3809e80/CHANGES.md). `\DeclareInnerCiteDelim` is `\DeclareInnerCiteDelims` now.*

---

If you don't want to use `biblatex-ext` and prefer the standard `numeric` style instead you need.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{namelabeldelim}}%
     \printtext{\bibopenparen}\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}
    {\setunit{}%
     \printtext{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}}
    {\setunit{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}%
       \textcitedelim}}}
\makeatother
```

Actually it would be enough to redefine only `textcite`, because `biblatex` tries very hard to match the brackets properly. But I consider it good practice to also define the `textcite:postnote` to use the matching brackets.

Comment: Nice package indeed!  :)